# How to Define Style For an Element Specified by JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, supersized

I am using this full background slideshow background by Supersized (http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/fade.html). As you can see from the source code, the photos, titles, and urls are inputted via jQuery.

```
<div id="slidecaption"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
        jQuery(function($){

            $.supersized({

                // Functionality
                slide_interval          :   3000,       // Length between transitions
                transition              :   1,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   700,        // Speed of transition

                // Components                           
                slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'number', 'name', 'blank')
                slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-1.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-1.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/'},
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-2.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-2.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/'},  
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-3.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-3.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/'},
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-1.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-1.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/'},
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-2.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-2.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/'},
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-3.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-3.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/'},
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-1.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-1.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/06/brooke-shaden/'},
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-2.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-2.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/06/brooke-shaden/'},
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-3.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-3.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/06/brooke-shaden/'}
                                            ]

            });
        });

    </script>
```

How do I go about changing or adding a class to the title so that I can style the caption as a white or dark color, so it's easier to read, based on the background?

Comment: Inspect the DOM, find a path that to the titles that can be targeted with a selector, and use that.

Comment: @adeneo got it figured out. It is the id slidecaption that I need to target. However, how do I add a class (for a different color) depending on the background?

Answer (score 0):

In any browser, right click the text (or any element) on the page and click `"Inspect Element"`.

You will see a new dialog part which has the whole `DOM structure` (your `HTML`). Because with jQuery libraries a lot of elements are added dynamically, you don't see them in your `HTML` file.

After you see your selected element check what class it has. Based on that class do your styling. If it has no class, do `CSS` for that element.

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible but this time I thought to apply

```css
text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
```

this now has made caption more visible